# Capacitance of capcitor with complex dielectric material

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, dielectric

How do I find capacitance of capacitor if we insert a material in capacitor that has a dielectric constant which depends on position inside a capacitor?

For example two plates of capacitor filled with some artificial material. Dieelctric constant at the left plate is zero and rises as exponential function till it reaches the right plate.

How would I calculate that?

I tried to put capacitor on very riny slices so that dielectric constant in each slice wouldn't change much. But then I get some summation sequence and I have troubles converting that to integral form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the concept of capacitance of the medium, use the concept of [elastance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastance), which is the reciprocal of the capacitance:  $S = 1/C$.  In particular, for several capacitors in series, their elastances add directly:
$$S_\text{eq} =  S_1 + S_2 + ...
$$
Moreover, the elastance of a pair of parallel plates is proportional to the distance between them:
$$
S = \frac{d}{\kappa \epsilon_0 A}
$$
These two properties make it straightforward to imagine subdividing the space between the plates into a large number of infinitesimally small spaces of width $dx$, calculating the infinitesimal elastance $dS$ of each space, and then summing them all up with an integral to get the total elastance.